# Energy from an inductor breakdown

Tags: capacitor, inductor, energy

This post is inspired by a lesson on the allaboutcircuits education website. In chapter 15 of Direct Current there is a heading ["Inductors and Calculus"](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-15/inductors-and-calculus/) -  At the bottom of the topic there is a circuit showing a neon bulb in parallel with an inductor and the sentence

> "If current through an inductor is forced to change very rapidly, very
>   high voltages will be produced."

Well I am thinking why not change the bulb for a capacitor and capture the energy? The formula for energy of a capacitor is .5CV^2. Therefore the higher the voltage the more energy and the formula for voltage in an inductor is V = L*di/dt. At the instant the switch is turned of di would be at a maximum and dt a minimum giving a large V.

I'm not sure how this would be done. But why not siphon of some of the energy to repeat the procedure instead of using a battery. The rest could be used to power a load. This should be able to continue indefinitely as the breakdown voltage is much larger than the voltage required to charge up the inductor.

One idea I have is to use 2 capacitors in parallel with the inductor. One with a small capacitance to keep the circuit running and a larger one for the load. The load capacitor would have to use diodes?

My guess is to prevent it emptying back into the inductor. It would also be necessary to employ a switch to obtain the high breakdown voltage. Timing would also be an issue with the larger capacitor taking longer to charge. This just seems too simple so I'm wondering why it won't work?

Comment: In this website we obey the Laws of Thermodinamics

Comment: Helpfull comment - not.

Answer (score 3):

> But why not siphon of some of the energy to repeat the procedure instead of using a battery. The rest could be used to power a load. This should be able to continue indefinitely ...

There is no way to extract energy continuously from a system. Call it perpetual motion, over unity, free energy, whatever, it doesn't work, we don't pander to that here. We can simply say 'it's not going to work'. We can figure out why for any particular arrangement of gears, pulleys, weights, motors afterwards.

In your specific case of charging an inductor and then interrupting the current; while you can get a high voltage generated, the energy you can get out is no more than the energy you put in. The high voltage across the inductor will change the current quickly, so you can have a current flowing at high voltage (high power) for a short time, or low voltage (low power) for a long time, and in each case the energy delivered (apart from slightly different losses) will be the same. You can't get current flowing at a high voltage for a long time.

What does work very well with two capacitors, an inductor and suitable switches is a way to transfer almost all of the energy from one capacitor to the other. You charge the inductor from one capacitor, and then use the inductor to charge the other capacitor.

Comment: That makes sense. It seems the formula for energy in a capacitor only applies if a constant voltage is applied until it is fully charged. Would that be the case?

Comment: The formula for energy in a capacitor only applies if the capacitance is constant, otherwise you have to integrate the amount of energy you've put into it.

Comment: How about this scenario. If a capacitor is charged with x volts for 0.1 secs. Another capacitor of the same capacitance is charged with x volts for 1 second. Would the second capacitor have more energy?

Comment: @user1897830 Your question is incoherent. You can charge a capacitor *to* x volts, or you can charge a capacitor with a current of I amps for t seconds. However, if you have two capacitors of the same capacitance, connect both to x volts through some resistance, and they both fully (in the limit) charge in 0.1 seconds, then leaving the other connected for 1 second won't store any more energy, as no current is flowing. If they don't fully charge to x volts, then the first will store less energy, as it's charged to a lower voltage.

Comment: The answer I was looking for was the for formula for the time it takes to charge a capacitor. I found it with google - t = 5RC. After that period of time the capacitors energy could be calculated with the formula - w = 0.5CV^2.

Comment: @user1897830 5RC is not the time it takes to charge a capacitor, it's the time it takes to get to around 99%. In your last comment, you didn't specify an R, so RC was not relevant. If that was the answer you were looking for, why didn't you ask how long it took to charge a capacitor? Note I used the expression 'fully (in the limit)'. This means 'as close as we want for this particular approximation'. E is only equal to 0.5CV^2 if the capacitance stays constant during the charging time, ceramic capacitors especially would fall foul of this.

Comment: It looks as if you two speak on different wavelengths.

Answer (score 2):

There is energy stored in an inductor with current flowing through it. Some of that energy could be captured when you turn off the circuit. But you can't capture it just by putting a capacitor in parallel with the inductor. What will happen is that current will flow back and forth into the capacitor until all the stored energy is dissipated in the series resistance of the inductor and capacitor.

You could have yet another switch. So that once the inductor current drops to zero, and the capacitor voltage has peaked, at that exact moment you disconnect the capacitor from the inductor. Then you can connect the capacitor up to something else that could benefit from the stored energy.

I think most of the time it is more trouble than it is worth. Note that the energy stored in the inductor or capacitor is finite. If you use it, you can't get it back again unless you add energy to the system some other way.

Comment: Any ideas on the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

(a) yes you can store the inductor's energy in a capacitor

(b) yes you need a diode between the inductor and capacitor so that when the inductor voltage starts falling, the diode turns off and keeps the charge stored on the capacitor. This is the simplest form of "switch" in mkeith's answer.

(c) yes another capacitor in parallel with the inductor will keep the oscillation going ... but note that by itself, it won't return the inductor to a high enough voltage to turn the diode on again, you need a source of energy to boost the oscillation again. But really, you knew that from the conservation of energy. Also note that an L-C resonant circuit limits the rate of change of current to a sinusoidal function, therefore limiting the peak voltage.

Congratulations, if you implement (a) and (b) successfully, you have invented the flyback converter, aka boost converter. You just need to repeat the process of switching the current on and off again to keep it going, to run a load off the higher voltage.

Add (c) and you have invented the resonant flyback converter.

Comment: Your on my wavelength Brian.